# Running hibernate tool annotation generation without the "catalog" attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, code-generation, annotations

when i run my hibernate tools
it reads from the db and create java classes for each tables,
and a java class for composite primary keys.
that's great.

the problem is this line

```
@Table(name="tst_feature"
    ,catalog="tstdb"
)
```

while the table name is required, the "catalog" attribute is not required.
sometimes i want to use "tstdb", sometimes i want to use "tstdev"

i thought which db was chosen depends on the jdbc connection url
but when i change the jdbc url to point to "tstdev", it is still using "tstdb"

so,
i know what must be done,
just don't know how its is done
my options are

- suppress the generation of the "catalog" attribute
  currently i'm doing this manually (not very productive)
  or i could write a program that parses the java file and remove the attribute manually
  but i'm hoping i don't have to

OR

- find a way to tell hibernate to ignore the "catalog" attribute and use the schema that is explicitly specified.
  i don't know the exact setting i have to change to achive this, or even if the option is available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to follow 3 steps -

1) In the `hibernate.cfg.xml`, add this property

```
hibernate.default_catalog = MyDatabaseName
```

(as specified in above post)

2) In the `hibernate.reveng.xml`, add all the table filters like this

```
table-filter match-name="MyTableName"
```

(just this, no catalog name here)

3) Regenerate hibernate code

You will not see any catalog name in any of the `*.hbm.xml` files.

I have used Eclipse Galileo and Hibernate-3.2.4.GA.

Answer (score 1):

There is a customization to the generation, that will tell what tables to put in what catalog.

You can specify the catalogue manually (in reveng file, `<table>` element), or programmatically (in your custom ReverseEngineeringStrategy class if I remember well).

Also, I recently had to modify the generation templates.

See the reference documentation :

- http://docs.jboss.org/tools/archive/3.0.1.GA/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#hibernaterevengxmlfile
  you can customize the catalogue of each of your tables manually
- https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/tools/viewlets/custom_reverse_engineering.htm watch a movie that explains a lot ...
- http://docs.jboss.org/tools/archive/3.0.1.GA/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#d0e5363 for customizing the templates (I start with the directory that's closest to my needs, copy all of them in my own directory, then edit as will)

Sorry, this could get more precise, but I don't have access to my work computer right now.

Comment: table element selects tables from the catalogs,
yes.
but that's not i want.

i want the entity to be generated without the "catalog" attribute

if the catalog attribute is there, no matter what my jdbc url is, it would still point to the same schema,

i want to be able to switch schema without re-generating the entities.

Comment: i took a look at the ftl files
there is a line that says
<#if clazz.table.catalog?exists>
    ,catalog="${clazz.table.catalog}"
</#if>
any idea on how do i set this to false?

Comment: i figured it out
use
<property name="default_catalog">xxx</property>
in you hibernate.cfg.xml file

Answer (score 0):

The attribute catalog is a "connection" attribute and should be specified in the "connection" config file `hibernate.cfg.xml` and NOT in a "data" config file `*.hbm.xml`.

I generate hibernate code via ant task `<hibernatetool>` and I put this replace task after regeneration (replace schema-name with your database).

```
<replace dir='../src' token='catalog="schema-name"' value=''>
```

So, after generation, attribute catalog has been removed.

This is a workaround, but code generated works in my development a production environment with different schema-name.